# Xalan DLL missing

Tags: c++, dll, xalan

I'm trying to compile a sample visual C++ 2008 project to test Xalan-C++ library. When I try to compile the project, it gives an error saying "xalan-c_1_11d.dll is missing". When I checked the the library files there were no .DLL files at all, only static libraries. Is there any way for me to resolve this issue without having to compile Xalan-C++ library myself? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the linking model to static instead of dynamic. In VC++ there is an option of library linking which has Single threaded static, single threaded dll, multi threaded static and multi threaded dll. you need to change that.

also there must be a lib file that the linker would use to link the function calls from your dll. you can instruct the compiler using the following syntax:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "mylib.lib")
```

this will link the lib file to your program. Also the ending of name in "d" myxxxd.lib mentions that compiler is looking for the debug version. try to change the build from debug to release to see if that helps